# NSTextView - drawing custom glyphs that can't be edited

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, text, nstextview

I'm making an outliner using NSTextView.  The outline: method on NSTextView doesn't quite capture what I need, so I've rolled my own using the typesetter/formatter.  Now, I need to show the outline symbols next to each line fragment.  How do you draw these symbols in such a way that the user cannot edit them?  Any thoughts?

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

I don't want the cursor to be able to even cross the outline symbols (symbols like •, i, 1, etc).  I'm thinking I will need to draw custom line fragments that can't be selected.  Or perhaps overlay some other view that draws the symbols.  I might even want symbols next to these outline symbols that can collapse outline elements.  I'm looking more for architecture solutions than particular methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSTextView delegate method [-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and respond with NO for your uneditable range.

**Update based on comments**

Why not play with the margins of your text container, then use NSTextView's -drawViewBackgroundInRect: to draw the UI element in the margin?

Comment: Right, but how do you draw the actual outline symbols such that the cursor can't even hit them.  That's the real issue at hand.  I'm thinking they need to be drawn in their own frame or something.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. Updating my answer.

Comment: If I draw it in the background, would I be able to put clickable collapse triangles?

Comment: You can add subviews to the text view, so sure. But they'd draw themselves so if that's what you were trying to draw, then you're going the wrong way. :-) If it's an interactive control you want, add it as a subviews and manage its placement. But keep the margin suggestion - you'll need the room. :-)